# Override alter.inc in child theme

Tags: 7

Bootstrap.js is breaking a menu plugin I'm using. It's called with this

```
  $bootstrap = $theme_path . '/js/bootstrap.js';
  $js[$bootstrap] = drupal_js_defaults($bootstrap);
  $js[$bootstrap]['group'] = JS_THEME;
  $js[$bootstrap]['scope'] = 'footer';
```

in themes/bootstrap/theme/alter.inc. I tried putting a modified alter.inc inside themes/child_theme/theme/ but it doesn't work. Is there a function I can use to override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to remove bootstrap.js you can do it this way:

```
function YOURTHEME_js_alter(&$js) {  
  $bootstrap = drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap') . '/js/bootstrap.js';
  unset($js[$bootstrap]);
}
```

It might fix your menu plugin but it'll remove every drupal specific bootstrap js code (tabs, popovers, tooltips and anchors stuff).

Comment: Is there a way I can remove one part of it?       jQueryscrollableElement.once('bootstrap-anchors', function () {
        jQueryscrollableElement.on('click.bootstrap-anchors', 'a[href*="#"]:not([data-toggle],[data-target])', function(e) {
          this.scrollTo(e);
        });
      }); is what's breaking my plugin

Comment: Go to admin/appearance/settings/yourtheme, Javascript tab, uncheck smooth scrolling. That should do it.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. I get "this.scrollTo is not a function"

Comment: Oh, looking at the actual code, disabling anchor fixing should do it.

Comment: you deleted your comment on my other post but I think you're onto something... what's the syntax for printing a field? I tried a few different ways but got errors.

Comment: Hi, my comment wasn't entirely correct in that `render()` takes array in, yes, but it can also deal with basic types too. I looked at its code after commenting so I figured I might as well remove my comment.